# C++, const reference is actually faster than move?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, move, const-reference

After testing this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


void x(std::vector<std::string>&& v){ }

void y(const std::vector<std::string>& v) { }

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v = {};

    auto tp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
        x(std::move(v));

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - tp);

    std::cout << "1- It took: "  << time.count() << " seconds\n";

    tp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
        y(v);

    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - tp);

    std::cout << "2- It took: " << time.count() << " seconds\n";

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I get that using const-reference is actually ~15s faster than using move semantics, why is that? I thought that move semantics were faster, else, why would they add them? What did I get wrong about move semantics? thanks

Comment: Your functions are empty, you're not testing anything but the parameter passing setup - that is if the calls aren't optimized out entirely. Maybe one gets optimized and the other doesn't? You should look at or post the generated code.

Comment: The fact that your `x` takes a `&&` indicates you don't understand move semantics. Consider reading [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics).

Comment: Moving is an optimization of _copy_ (for xvalues), not of passing by reference. Of course passing a simple reference is faster.

Comment: Have you enabled optimization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. Here is a simpler version of your code, substituted with `int` and cleaned up. Here is the assembly version of the code, compiled with `-std=c++11 -02`:

https://goo.gl/6MWLNp

**There is  NO difference between the assembly for the rvalue and lvalue functions.** Whatever is the cause doesn't matter because the test itself doesn't make use of move semantics.

**The reason is probably because the compiler optimizes both functions to the same assembly.** You're not doing anything with either, so there's no point in doing anything different in the assembly than a simple `ret`.

Here is a better example, this time, swapping the first two items in the vector:

https://goo.gl/Sp6sk4

**Ironically, you can see that the second function actually just calls the rvalue reference version automatically as a part of its execution.**

Assuming that a function A which calls B is slower than just executing the function B, the speed of `x()` should outperform `y()`.

---

<s>`std::move()` itself has an additional cost. All things else being constant, calling `std::move()` is more costly than not calling `std::move()`. This is why the "move semantics" is slower in the code you gave us. **In reality, the code is slower because you're not actually doing anything--both functions simply return as soon as they execute. You can also see that one version appears to call `std::move()` while the other doesn't.**</s>

**Edit: The above doesn't appear to be true. `std::move()` is not usually a true function call; it is mainly a `static_cast<T&&>` that depends on some template stuff.**

In the example I gave you, I'm actually making use of the move semantics. Most of the assembly is more important, but you can see that `y()` calls `x()` as a part of its execution. `y()` should therefore be slower than `x()`.

***tl;dr: You're not actually using move semantics because your functions don't need to do anything at all. Make the functions use copying/moving, and you'll see that even the assembly uses part of the "move semantics" code as a part of its copying code.***

Comment: Are you sure that there is a cost to calling move? I thought it's just a reinterpret cast; which has no runtime cost, and the function itself will be inlined so no overhead there.

Comment: Thanks for answering politely. I will take all this into account, the assembly code made it clear to me. Again, thanks.

Comment: @NirFriedman Yeah you're right; I changed the post to reflect this

Comment: The example gcc.godbolt.org/z/79zT4xe8e is wrong as iterates over already moved object v1, en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move, read the Note: If the argument identifies a resource-owning object, these overloads have the option, but aren't required, to move any resources held by the argument. I other words, it is not guaranteed, you move the object you intended as the object can be in inconsitent state. Anyway, it makes no sense to bind to a const rvalue references.